# Blazor server-side async deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock, blazor-server-side

I have an async method that I want to call from blazor compoment. I need to call it directly from component, not from its lifecycle hooks (where it works well).

I am not sure why some of my cases work and some don't.

I know that synchronously waiting for an async Task inside `ASP/UI context` thread may casue deadlock. But here, the situation is little different since `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't help.

My assumption is that it has somethig to do with fact, that in `Blazor server-side` there are multiple possible UI threads, so when I set `ConfigureAwait(false)` then in most cases the rest of work will be processd by different, but still `UI` thread.

Can someone explain what's happening there?

Here is my component's code (simplified):

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject AsyncTaskService TaskService

//works
<p>Google request sync result: @TaskService.RequestGoogle()</p>

//deadlock
<p>Google request async result #1: @TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync().Result</p>

//deadlock
<p>Google request async result #2: @TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()</p>

//works (because ThreadPoolThread performs requesting?)
<p>Google request async result #3: @(Task.Run(() => TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync()).Result)</p>

//can not compile
<p>Google request async result #4: @await TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync()</p>
```

AsyncTaskService:

```
public class AsyncTaskService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public AsyncTaskService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this._httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public string RequestGoogle()
    {
        var webResponse = _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result;
        var result = webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<string> RequestGoogleAsync()
    {
        var webResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com");
        var result = webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RequestGoogleAsync` doesn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` after `GetAsync`; it needs to be used all the way down.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay will try it

Comment: It's not the `await` that blocks but the `.Result`. Your code should be in OnInitialziedAsync, _"I need to call it directly from component, not from its lifecycle hooks"_ is nonsense. You are painting yourself in a corner.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know. I wrote `waiting` so it may be `.Result` or `.Wait()`. The purpose of question was not to ask how to avoid, but to understand the root cause of situation that seemed strange to me. And the root cause was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that synchronously waiting for an async Task inside ASP/UI context thread may casue deadlock. But here, the situation is little different since ConfigureAwait(false) doesn't help.

It's not different, actually. It's the [exact same deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The problem with using `ConfigureAwait(false)` as a [blocking hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-blocking-hack) is that it needs to be applied to *every* `await` within the transitive closure of all methods called from the point of the blocking. So for the blocking code `TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, that means that `TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync` has to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await`, *and* every method that `TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync` calls has to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await`, *and* every method that those methods call have to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await`, *all the way down*. Including code you don't control (library/framework code). And if you (or the library/framework code) miss even a single one, then you have a potential deadlock.

So, to walk through:

```
//deadlock
<p>Google request async result #2: @TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()</p>
```

^ The `ConfigureAwait(false)` here does exactly nothing because there's no `await` being configured.

```
//works (because ThreadPoolThread performs requesting?)
<p>Google request async result #3: @(Task.Run(() => TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync()).Result)</p>
```

^ This one [works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-thread-pool-hack) because the thread pool doesn't have a "context" to capture, so the deadlock is avoided.

```
//can not compile
<p>Google request async result #4: @await TaskService.RequestGoogleAsync()</p>
```

^ This one would be ideal. I recommend that you do not block on asynchronous code (or on I/O).

If you cannot use `await` here, then you should use `await` before this point. I'm not that familiar with Blazor but with MVC it was common to use `await` when determining the model, which was then passed to the (synchronous) view. It sounds to me that lifecycle hooks may be the better solution.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen. I hoped you will put an answer here. That also answers my concerns that this applies also to libraries and third party code that is out of my control. So it's like walking on a thin ice.